# Connect from custom ephemeral RMI port in the create registry action

Tags: java, server, port, rmi

I'm developing a standalone application that uses Java 6 with RMI in Windows 7.

What I've read is that **[createRegistry](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/rmi/registry/LocateRegistry.html)** action uses by default the port **1099** and it's perfect. Following some tutorials I have this code as my example:

```
LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1099, new SocketFactory(), new SocketFactory());

Random r = new Random();

int nextPort = r.nextInt(100 + 1) + 50000;

PowerServiceImpl powerServiceImpl = new PowerServiceImpl(nextPort);

Naming.rebind("rmi://10.1.1.100:1099/PowerService", powerServiceImpl);
```

When I create the registry, I assign the default and I use it successfuly in the 1099 port as it's seen in this image:

[image]

In the image, it is shown the **1099** as the port opened in the "server" and a random port ([ephemeral](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65475/ephemeral-port-what-is-it-and-what-does-it-do)) that establishes connection with it.

What I want to achieve is to set a custom port as the ephemeral port (**instead of 53559 in image it could be 50005 for example**) to establish connection with the server (1099).

Is there a way to implement this?

Am I missing something?

Thanks and regards

Comment: Why? If you have an firewall rule about outbound port numbers, it should be removed. It adds nothing to security, and unimplementability to applications. Specifically, you won't be able to make connections within two minutes of each other. NB You don't need a random number generator. Just specify zero. I don't see what 'in the `createRegistry()` action' has to do with it. It doesn't create any connections.

Comment: The goal is to have firewall for security purposes. The random port is used to create ports inside a range for future connections. As the image shows, when createRegistry() method is invoked, it creates a connection for 1099 and an ephemeral port, that ephemeral port is what I want to customize. Thanks, I have also edited my question to include the ephemeral term.

Comment: As I have already told you, no genuine security purpose is accomplished by your goal, and it suffers from the other problem I mentioned. Also you won't be able to call remote methods in different threads. Review your requirement.

Comment: Can you suggest me some link to read some about it please? Thanks

Comment: I suggest that whoever is imposing this nonsense about outbound port numbers be (a) told it isn't practically implementable, and (b) asked what security benefit is supposed to accrue. I've been making this statement for nearly thirty years and I have never been told any answer to that at all, let alone a plausible one. Show them this thread if necessary.